# Displaying file type icons in a web app?

Tags: html, css, icons, mime-types, file-type

In Desktop applications, you can usually get at the underlying operating system's icon for a particular filetype and display that to the user. In a web app, I'm restricted from such functionality, so it looks like I probably need to provide my own icon set.

Does anyone know of any well-licensed free icon sets for common icon types? I found a [project on github](https://github.com/marcus/file-type-icons/tree/master/file_icons), but it's missing some of the types I need (open document, docx, bitmap, etc.)

Comment: May be you should try finding icons on [IconFinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/) is a good search engine for this. It also details licenses associated with each of the icons.

Comment: "Free for non-commercial use" returns for all of the usable .docx images. Worthless.

Comment: Maybe try refining the search? `document` instead of `docx` maybe?

Comment: Even with that, most are GPL (no version specified, so I can't use it in case it's GPL3) or free for non-commercial. I really hit nothing but dead ends on this searcher.